# Voltage regulator for esp8266

Tags: voltage-regulator, esp8266

Below is the link for the famous smt module ESP8266-12E. In the link appears the module and another component which package is 8 SOIC. I am thinking that it should be the voltage regulator for the esp module. What are you thinking? It's written "SergMicro 25Q32ASSC6 1403" when searching with Google about any of those items I can not find any result. Does someone know what is this component?

Link : https://www.adafruit.com/products/2491

[image: ESP8266-12E]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the SPI Flash needed for the ESP8266. It is a standard SPI 32 M-Bit (4 MegaByte) flash eeprom 25Q32, so any similar data sheet for similar brands will work. It is not a regulator. ***The module you are looking at is the bare ESP8266 module.***

It does not include the typical breakout board, which brings the pins out to standard 0.1" headers, has reverse voltage protection, a linear regulator, or extra features. Adafruit sells the completed module + breakout as [the Adafruit HUZZAH ESP8266 breakout](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2471).

Comment: thank you, i am trying now to replace it. When i have removed it i couldn t upload any more my arduino Sketch. ( i have another module) So i suppose that the bootloader save always the user prog in this additional Flash Memory chip! I mean no Chance to upload the Sketch directely to the Flash Memory of the esp chip itself ( well in that case i suppose the bootloader must be changed).